# SQL Query on 4 tables : Very Complex?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, doctrine

i have four tables

```
alert:
    * monitor_id
    * group_id

group:
    * group_id

user:
    * user_id
    * email

user_group:
    * group_id
    * user_id
```

is it possible to have the user's mail using just the monitor_id ?
if yes! is it possible in only one query?
please help me whether by the sql query or the doctrine !

Comment: "the user"  is a single user, but a row in alert references a group. So do you want all emails of all user's in one group?

Comment: i want emails  of all users belonging to all groups that the monitor is related to! you see?

Comment: Call that complex? Beginner complexity ;) Try joining 30 tables in a 4 page statement ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user.email FROM user 
inner join user_group on user.user_id=user_group.user_id 
inner join alert on  alert.group_id=user_group.group_id
where alert.monitor_id = provided_monitor_id
```

Previous one with Shahbaz comments.

```
SELECT * FROM user inner join user_group on user.user_id=user_group.user_id 
inner join  group on user_group.group_id=group.group_id inner 
join alert on  alert.group_id=group.group_id
group by user.user_id
```

Edit (by Shahbaz): To help explain how the command works:

When you have two tables sharing a field (a variable if you like), you can `join` the two tables (also called `inner join`), resulting in a bigger table combining the data from the two tables (you could even do it if there are no sharing fields). Let's go through this with an example:

Table People: fields: pid, pname, pjob

with entries

- (0, 'Alice', 'Student')
- (1, 'Bob', 'factory worker')
- (2, 'clara', 'nurse')

Table Jobs: fields: jname, jpay

with entries

- ('teacher', 1000)
- ('student', 0)
- ('factory worker', 2000)

Now if you say `People join Jobs` you get a table with 9 entries, having:

fields: pid, pname, pjob, jname, jpay

with entries

- (0, 'Alice', 'student', 'teacher', 1000)
- (0, 'Alice', 'student', 'student', 0)
- (0, 'Alice', 'student', 'factory worker', 2000)
- (1, 'Bob', 'factory worker', 'teacher', 1000)
- (1, 'Bob', 'factory worker', 'student', 0)
- (1, 'Bob', 'factory worker', 'factory worker', 2000)
- (2, 'Clara', 'nurse', 'teacher', 1000)
- (2, 'Clara', 'nurse', 'student', 0)
- (2, 'Clara', 'nurse', 'factory worker', 2000)

As you can see this is not such a good table! You can use the `on` condition in `join` to extract information that are relevant to each other. For example, we may want to see the pay of each people. Therefore, the People.pjob should equal to Jobs.jname so, if you say `People join Jobs on People.pjob=Jobs.jname` you get a table having:

fields: pid, pname, pjob, jname, jpay

with entries

- (0, 'Alice', 'student', 'student', 0)
- (1, 'Bob', 'factory worker', 'factory worker', 2000)

Note that Clara's job didn't exist in Jobs table and thus she is not present in the final table.

While `inner join` gives you data from the two tables that match, you may want to get data of the tables even if there is no matching on the other side. This is called `outer join`. In this example `People outer join Jobs` yields a table having

fields: pid, pname, pjob, jname, jpay

with entries

- (0, 'Alice', 'student', 'student', 0)
- (1, 'Bob', 'factory worker', 'factory worker', 2000)
- (2, 'Clara', 'nurse', `null`, `null`)
- (`null`, `null`, `null`, 'teacher', 1000)

If you want only the table on the left side of the `outer join` to be included even if unmatched, use `left outer join` (in this case, the 'Clara' row will be present and not the 'teacher' row). Likewise, `right outer join` gives rows from the right table even if unmatched, but not the left table.

Finally, you must already know what `select` does, it simply returns a table with selected columns from the provided column (`*` selecting all columns). The given table could be just the name of a table, or any other table formed with sql commands (tables created with `select` command itself (in which case don't hesitate to use parenthesis), tables create with `join` command etc). If you understand this recursive nature of SQL, you can create commands as complicated as you like. Just imagine that each operation on tables, yields another table that you can simply use in conjunction with other operations as if that table was a simple stored named table!

Comment: Just e note. You forgot to put the where clause "Where alert.monitor_id = @monitor_id". the Op is asking a query to have results from a given monitor_id.

Comment: A few points: I don't see the reason to join in `group` - you can link driectly from user to user_group to alert; I don't see the need for the GROUP BY; Doing a SELECT * is a waste of effort. If the only desired field is email, it should be specified.

Comment: @Doug-Kress Agree, I missed that it's necessary only one field. So this is a cause of group by. Edited.

Comment: here is what i did :

    SELECT u.email_address
    FROM sf_guard_user u
    JOIN sf_guard_user_group ug ON ug.user_id = u.id
    WHERE ug.group_id
    IN (
    
    SELECT group_id
    FROM alert
    WHERE monitor_id =1
    )

AND it seems to be working!
what do you think?

Comment: @SymFoNyBegginer  This is another approach. It seems it will take more time than ordinary join. Anyway You should check explain plan for each of query and select the best. Run explain query ....

Comment: @Shahbaz, I Approved the edit because you put sooooo much work into it, but methinks it would make more sense for you to make this into an answer of your own. You can then just refer to Andrej's answer. That way you will get the (much deserved) upvotes. Now Andrej gets any upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the monitor_id to get a users email then do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  u.user_id
  u.email
FROM `user` u
INNER JOIN user_group ug ON u.user_id = ug.user_id 
INNER JOIN `group` g ON ug.group_id = g.group_id 
INNER JOIN alert a ON a.group_id = g.group_id
WHERE a.monitor_id = '1548'
```

Because the path from monitor_id to user.email goes through all the tables, your will need all those joins.
As long as you have indexed (!) all fields used in the joins the runtime should be fast.

Comment: here is what i did :

    SELECT u.email_address
    FROM sf_guard_user u
    JOIN sf_guard_user_group ug ON ug.user_id = u.id
    WHERE ug.group_id
    IN (
    
    SELECT group_id
    FROM alert
    WHERE monitor_id =1
    )

AND it seems to be working!
what do you think?

Comment: IN (select ....) will work, but can be very slow. MySQL is notorious for not optimizing that kind of query, for this reason I'd recommend using joins.

Answer (score 0):

Another way (not using `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`):

```
SELECT 
    u.user_id
  , u.email
FROM `user` AS u
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM alert AS a 
          JOIN `group` AS g
            ON g.group_id = a.group_id 
          JOIN user_group AS ug
            ON ug.group_id = g.group_id
        WHERE ug.user_id = u.user_id 
          AND a.monitor_id = @monitorId      -- the monintor_id to be checked
      )
```

---

**Note**: it's not good practice to have tables or fields named with keywords or reserved words like `user` and even worse `group`.